# Axios Fedex Docs is not understandable

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, fedex

Hello I try to pull fedex tracking product info with axios.
but here doc https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-us/catalog/track/v1/docs.html#operation/Track%20by%20Tracking%20Number is not understandable.
here my code

```js
import axios from "axios"
( ()=>{
const config = {
    method:`post`,
    url: "https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/track/v1/trackingnumbers",
    headers:{
    "Content-Type" : "application/json",
    "X-locale": "en_US",
    "Authorization":"Bearer blabla"
}
data:JSON.stringify(<trackingNumber>)

}
 const  axi =   axios(config).then(res=> console.log(res.data))
    


})()
```

here is the instance tracking number for you: 277607960166
what am I missing here I cannot figure out.

Answer (score 1):

The sandbox API credentials are not immediately usable when creating a new account, hope it helps you.

[Getting the OAuth token from fedex to use for track API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70490402/getting-the-oauth-token-from-fedex-to-use-for-track-api)